# C target - line number not correct

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am using ANTLR3C v3.4, here is a snippet of the grammar:

```
include_cmd
    : Include  Double_Quote  file_name  Double_Quote  
    {
        my_model->add_include($file_name.text, LT(0)->getLine(LT(0)));
    }
    ;
```

But I find that LT(0)->getLine(LT(0)) returns an incorrect line number, when it is the first line, LT() returns 3; when it is the 3rd line, returns 5. It seems there is always some offset.

Is this a bug in ANTLR3c or my using LT() is wrong? I assume LT(0) returns token "Include" and from it I get the line number.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything between the first and third line? Is it possible that you get line number of the beginning of next statement because antlr goes to the next token before it matches parsing rule?

Comment: Actually the problem I had is line number, not char position. I found that after changing LT(0)->getLine(LT(0)) to LT(0)->line, it is fine. I am not sure if this is best solution, but thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround was described here. The root cause is wrong initialization for input.

http://antlr.markmail.org/search/?q=Jim%20Idle#query:Jim%20Idle%20from%20list%3Aorg.antlr.antlr-interest%20from%3A%22Jim%20Idle%22+page:83+mid:rnvmkdec65rddzua+state:results

Or you can adapt this c++ target [patch](https://github.com/ibre5041/antlr3/commit/44b950aa80107ebb867ddf8a5b0bc22e470a6811)

Comment: It's really amazing that this simple fix still did not made it into the official source code. There are also 3 pull requests on Github for bugs in the runtime (2 from me): https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/pulls. Yet, also those never made it there (and probably never will).

Answer (score 0):

There's only a bug for the first line (and only the C target, from what I know). The initial values are probably not correctly set. I usually prefix the text to parse with a space char (as whitespaces are usually ignored). Select a different char if space is important to you. With that prefix the line number of the first token (the prefixed char) is wrong, but all others are correct then.

And keep in mind: line numbers are one-based (while character offsets are zero-based).